# Error: node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:668:15 - error TS2430: Interface 'FunctionMatchers<Fn>' incorrectly extends interface 'Matchers<any>'

Tags: angular, typescript, ngxs

Can anyone please tell why this issue is coming and how to resolve it.

Error: node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:668:15 - error TS2430: Interface 'FunctionMatchers' incorrectly extends interface 'Matchers'.    The types returned by 'toHaveBeenCalledWith(...)' are incompatible between these types.     Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'Promise'
interface FunctionMatchers extends Matchers {

Comment: You should update the code.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Updating @types/jasminewd2 fixed the issue for me

```
ng update @types/jasminewd2
```

Answer (score 2):

Updating jasmine worked for me

```
npm install @types/jasminewd2@latest
```